# Deploy from Codeship to DigitalOcean Droplet

Tags: digital-ocean, continuous-deployment, codeship

I've got a project setup in Codeship which hooks into my private Github repo, tests and builds. I want to use a custom script to deploy to my DigitalOcean Droplet (VM).

I thought of adding a git remote and using a simple push to the machine using SSH. This was based on the following [resource](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-automatic-deployment-with-git-with-a-vps). This fails because I would be pushing to a non-bare repo on the target machine.

Anyone aware of resources or ideas on how to deploy to the VM?

Answer (score 2):

Found on Codeship's documentation that you can use a custom script to run commands using `SSH`. Instructions are [here](https://documentation.codeship.com/continuous-deployment/deployment-with-ftp-sftp-scp/#run-commands-on-a-remote-server-via-ssh).